# What does a phone/broadband microfilter do exactly?

Tags: networking

My understanding is that home phone cables are not capable of handling fast ethernet due to only having 4 wires whereas CAT5 needs more (8?)

But then I wondered how the internet signal gets from the phone point to my router at speeds of approaching 100Mbps on fast fibre internet (I'm in the UK), and what role a microfiter plays in this? I believe there are twisted pairs to consider although this is the point I get lost.

So, what does a microfilter do and how does it do it?

Comment: It's a low-pass filter composed of inductors, capacitors and resistors.

Comment: Your question is kind of open-ended.  Answers could range from a few sentences that gloss over the gist to an entire course.  Can you refine what you're looking for and the level of detail?  Perhaps specific technical questions?  Getting into the electronic theory is likely to be considered off-topic here.

Comment: I think DavidPostill's answer is kind of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

#### How does the signal gets from the phone point to my router at speeds of 100Mbps?

Note - The following is a very simplified description.

The internet connection into your house can be terminated in several different ways, depending on what kind of internet you have.

The following assumes you have an ADSL connection and describes how this works in the UK..

- The connection from the telephone exchange will come to your house via the phone line.
- The phone line will be terminated at a phone socket.

  - The socket may have two ports, one for ADSL and one for a phone, or
  - The socket may have a filter plugged in to it, the filter will have two ports, one for ADSL and one for a phone
- The ADSL port will connect to the WAN port of the router, and if the router supports 100Mbps you will have an up to 100Mbps connection.
- The phone port will connect to your phone.

---

#### What role does a microfilter play?

Summary:

- The terms "micro-filter", "splitter" and "ADSL filter" mean the same thing.
- It separates analog voice (phone) traffic from data traffic.
- Voice (phone) traffic is at a lower frequency (< 4 KHz) than data traffic.
- The "telephone" outlet on the filter blocks the higher frequency signals which prevents the data signals from interfering with voice calls.
- A filter **must** be used for each telephone device that is connected to the socket.

---

**ADSL Filters & Splitters**

Note - some of the following is specific to UK ADSL connections.

> When your telephone line is ADSL enabled it is able to carry
>   information on different frequency ranges: ADSL uses the higher
>   frequencies to transmit data, whilst voice uses the lower frequency
>   band.
>
> Although you will still be able to use your telephone as normal once
>   your line is activated, the transmission of ADSL data on the line will
>   cause interference.
>
> In order that the ADSL data does not interfere with the normal voice
>   data (and vice-versa), you need to ensure you install a filter on each
>   device that uses the lower frequencies. These devices are telephones,
>   fax machines, answer phones, sky boxes.
>
> An ADSL filter (low pass filter) strips out any high frequency data
>   signals which are being carried on your phone line from the telephone
>   side of the filter.
>
> There are different types of splitter available for purchase, but they
>   all essentially work in a similar way.  However, it should be pointed
>   out that some of the cheaper filters available are not as reliable as
>   others, and are not able to filter or terminate the data signals as
>   effectively as they should. NTE5 adsl filtered faceplates are
>   generally the most effective since they filter your connection at the
>   point of entry.
>
> **Some common types of adsl filters**
>
> Type 1 (T-Filter)
>
> [image]
>
> Type 2 (Dongle)
>
> [image]
>
> ADSL NTE5 Faceplate
>
> [image]
>
> Filters will also "terminate" your ADSL line properly by ensuring that
>   data is not reflected back down the phone line which could cause
>   connection problems.
>
> A maximum of four micro-filters can be used on a BT phone line. This
>   corresponds to the recommended maximum number of items of telephony
>   equipment you can plug into a standard voice line - known as the
>   maximum Ringing Equivalent Number (REN).

Source [ADSL Filters & Splitters](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/splitters.htm)

---

#### Further Reading

- [How ADSL Works](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/equip.htm)

Comment: Thanks David, this pretty much answers by question. So the filter's two sockets are not re-wiring anything, just filtering the signal and the fact they're different sizes is fairly unimportant? It's a filter not an adapter basically.

Comment: I am still confused how you can often plug your router into a phone point that's not the master. Phone line is 4 wires (CAT3?) so how does it work at speeds faster than 10-BaseT... which actual wire(s) does the data/voice signal travel along?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Basically yes. They are different sizes because ethernet and phone cable have diferent plugs.

Comment: See [What is the theoretical maximum data transfer rate of a pair of wires in a phone cable?](//electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18914) for the gory details :)